# Adding additional info in transactional email depending on recipient

Tags: admin, email, transactional

Is it possible to edit transactional e-mail template so that some data will be included in an admin copy only? If not just by simple in-file expression, how can I achieve that? I want to insert an own-created layout handle in the message to admin.

Comment: Adminarea / System / Transactional emails ?

Comment: Ok, but I asked if there is a solution to include something only in copy of the email sent to admin

Answer (score 1):

Magento has two methods in sending copies to a specified email address in the backend: Bcc and Copy.

With Bcc there is definitely no way to have separate email content since the email is sent to both recipients in one email.

With the copy method a separate email is sent. However there is no way to specify a different template. Thus you have to modify/override Magento either to change that you can have multiple templates or add some variable to be used in the email.

The switch is implemented here: `loveknitting/public/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php:1321`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in the template alone.  You need to find where the email is being dispatched, then you can add your own custom text/html as a variable.  See:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
```

For example, you can define your own variable `admin_text` based on an arbitrary `isAdmin()` check:

```
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
    ->loadDefault('some_email_template')
    ->send(
        'email@example.com',
        'John Doe',
        array(
            'admin_text' => $this->isAdmin() ? 'Admin only text' : ''
        )
    );
```

Then in the `some_email_template` email template, add your variable with `{{var admin_text}}`